# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: mysql, json, django, python-2.7, utf-8

I'm using Django and ajax to print data to an HTML table with jQuery and JSON.

It was working until new data came and had `"ú@ñ"` type of characters and I got: 
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 4: invalid start byte`

I've read and tried many different possible reasons and it's still not working.

I've tried:

- saving my file in UTF-8 in Sublime Text and with a *file -bi myfile* I still get text/x-python; charset=us-ascii
- using `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of my views.py
- changing MySQL charset to CHARSET=utf8mb4 from CHARSET=latin1
- json.dumps(list(rows), default=datetime_handler), content_type="application/json", encoding='utf-8')

I'd rather avoid using .decode() for every string in my data but if there's no other solution, it's what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 1):

## -- encoding: utf-8

Is changing only encoding of the source file, meaning you can define variables/comments using non-ascii chars.

You can try to use

`json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it doesn't work either, I still get the same error.

Comment: It seems that utf-8 can not be used in the data you have, try to add json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")